# Process running without login on Windows

Tags: windows, authentication

I was wondering how TeamViewer (for example) does that.

It's not a system application, yet it fully runs before you log in to the system. 
Of course that doesn't mean you can bypass login screen as after you connect to the TV, you still see the login window.

By asking "how", I mean is it native Windows support or rather some low level hack? Does such process have some limitation(s)?

Comment: Maybe Windows service?

Comment: Yes, but you can't run software as a service "just like that" or can you?

Comment: A service **is** software. I don't understand the distinction you are trying to make here.

Comment: A service has configuration associated with it, stored in the registry.  It includes a username+password.  So it simply logs-in early, before the user does.